# Python unittest PUT method - getting error for status code

Tags: python, rest, api, unit-testing, python-unittest

This is my code for testing Trello API:

```
import string
import random
import requests
from settings import *

nonce = lambda x: ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits) for _ in range(10 if not x else x))

def get_board_detals(board_id):
    url = "https://trello.com/1/boards/" + board_id
    params = {"key":key,
          "token":token}
    return requests.get(url=url, params=params)

def post_board_name(board_name):
    url = "https://api.trello.com/1/boards"
    params = {"key": key,
          "token": token,
          "name": board_name}
    return requests.post(url=url, params=params)

def put_new_board_name(board_id):
    url = "https://api.trello.com/1/boards" + board_id
    params = {"key": key,
              "token": token}
    return requests.put(url=url, params=params)
```

and code for unittest:

```
import unittest
from board_details import *

class BoardDetails(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.name = nonce(10)

  def test_put_new_name(self):
        result_post = post_board_name(self.name)
        board_id = result_post.json()['id']

        result_put = put_new_board_name(board_id)
        self.assertEqual(result_put.status_code, 200)
        self.assertIn(result_put.json()['name'], self.name)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

When I run the code, I receive an error: `AssertionError: 404 != 200`.
I don't know why it is like that, can someone point out what's the reason for my error?

Comment: The URL you are accessing is returning 404 (not found) where you expected 200 OK. Check that URL via another method.

Comment: Yeah, I know what it means. Apologies, I formulated my question in a wrong way. I think there's an error either in the function, or in the method. I don't know where though.

Comment: OK no worries You are sure the URL is formed correctly at the time of call? .

Comment: You're right, it was wrong. It should be:  url = "https://api.trello.com/1/boards/" + board_id +"/name". But then I don't know what to put into the value, in:  params = {"key": key,
              "token": token,
              "value" : ?}
    return requests.put(url=url, params=params)

Comment: Ah, I think I managed to do this, it works :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it like this and it seems to work fine:

function:

```
def put_new_board_name(board_id, board_name):
    url = "https://api.trello.com/1/boards/" + board_id +"/name"
    params = {"key": key,
              "token": token,
              "value" : board_name}
    return requests.put(url=url, params=params)
```

and method:

```
def test_put_new_name(self):
    result_post = post_board_name(self.name)
    board_id = result_post.json()['id']

    result_put = put_new_board_name(board_id, board_name=self.name)
    self.assertEqual(result_put.status_code, 200)
    self.assertIn(result_put.json()['name'], self.name)
```